# How to return hierarchical anonymous type from LINQ Join?

Tags: linq-to-entities

How can I write a LINQ query that returns an hierachical anonymous type from a Join?

To clarify what I mean:
With WCF Data Services and Telerik WPF RadTreeView one can easily query and display hierarchical data:

```
    Dim q = _ctx1.Execute(Of NorthwindDataService.Customers)(New Uri("Customers\?$expand=Orders", UriKind.Relative))
    Dim td As New GridViewTableDefinition
    td.Relation = New Telerik.Windows.Data.PropertyRelation("Orders")
    RadGridView1.ChildTableDefinitions.Add(td)
    Dim r = q.ToList
    RadGridView1.ItemsSource = r
```

I want to join entities from different Data Services and display them in a hierachical grid.

```
Dim q = From c In _ctx1.Customers.ToList
Join o In _ctx2.Orders.ToList On c.CustomerID Equals o.CustomerID
  Select New With {c.CustomerID,
                       o.OrderId
                      }
```

The join works.
How can I "Select" an anonymous type with all properties of Customer plus an Orders property,
analogous to what a data service returns, that does directly bind to the grid?

Something like (this is not supported syntax!):
      Select New With {c.*,
                           .Orders = o
                          }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For two different data services you can use LINQ to Objects:**

```
Dim q1 = _ctx1.Customers.AsEnumerable()
Dim q2 = _ctx2.Orders.ToList()

Dim q = From c in q1
        Select New With {c.CustomerID,
                         q2.Where(o => o.CustomerID == c.CustomerID)
                        }
```

Again, apologies in advance for VB.NET syntax errors on my part.

**For one service:**

[It's almost always a mistake to use `join` in LINQ to Entities or LINQ to SQ](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/)L.

The direct analogy to your data services query is:

```
Dim q = _ctx1.Customers.Include("Orders");
```

But you can also project as with your L2E example:

```
Dim q = From c In _ctx1.Customers.ToList
        Select New With { c.CustomerID,
                          From o in c.Orders Select o.OrderID}
```

Apologies in advance for syntax errors; VB.NET is not my forte.

Comment: I am using two different data services so I have two different contexts: _ctx1 and _ctx2.
_ctx1 knows nothing about Orders

Comment: Then you need to split your queries into 2 LINQ to Entities queries and then `join` them in LINQ to objects. I'll give an example.